# After creating a new WPF project, the "Attach" button appears instead of the "Start" one

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have already tried to re-install VS 2019(community version). I'm using .Net 5.0.
[Here is the VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7igBc.png)

[And installed components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFw4x.png)

Comment: Your solution explorer is empty. Like PMF said you should add your project and open the csproj file.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open the **solution (.sln file)** or the **project (.csproj file)** that you created using Visual Studio and it should give you *Start* button instead of *Attach*.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with that project template. The solution (on the right side of the screen) does not contain the project. Right click on the entry in the solution explorer and say "Add->Existing project" and choose the csproj file that should be below the folder where the solution is.